# Selenium + XPath: element not found

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium + Python + Chromedriver script which should log in to a website and click on a download button which will download a CSV file.

Inspect details of download button is:

```
<button id="csv-button" class="block tiny-margin-top" data-args="csv">
      CSV
</button>
```

and XPath is:

```
//*[@id="csv-button"]
```

but it says XPath element not found when I run the script. Please find the code below:

```
click_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="csv-button"]')
click_button.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase of a unique *xpath* identifying the *WebElement* if you are seeing **element not found** exception you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with [`expected_conditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set to [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other code    
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='csv-button']"))).click()
```

To be more granular you can use :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other code    
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='block tiny-margin-top' and @id='csv-button']"))).click()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that your xpath is not quite correct. You are using single quotes where double are required and visa versa.

Try:

```
click_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='csv-button']")
click_button.click()
```

You can even try:

```
//button[@id='csv-button']
```

This will make the xpath search faster as it will look only for the button tags.

Comment: No. In Python there are no such rules for using single and double quotes, so `"//*[@id='csv-button']"` is correct as well as `'//*[@id="csv-button"]'`

Answer (score 0):

single quotes should come in the double quotes. Please see below

```
click_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='csv-button']")

click_button.click()
```

see the change here:

```
('//*[@id="csv-button"]')   ---> ("//*[@id='csv-button']")
```